# How to write a custom ISerializer in protobuf-net

Tags: protobuf-net

I am in the middle of converting serialization in our huge project from BinarySerializers to ProtoBuf, using protobuf-net library.

I have some classes where members have the type `object`, which needs some custom logic to include the type name before being able to deserialize to member again.

This is quite easy if I just use a surrogate - but I am concerned that this would result in unnecessary many allocations.

I would rather just implement a custom Serializer, which seems to be possible through `[ProtoContryt(Serializer=typeof(CustomSerializer)]`

Is there a documentation on how to implement such a serializer? In particular the property `SerializerFeatures` is not very clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The truth is: this is an advanced API that is not really very external-user-friendly; it is mainly designed for internal usage.

The `SerializerFeatures` describes a wide range of flags, but primarily what is needed is a *category* and a *wire-type*; the *category* tells it *what* we're doing, and the *wire-type* tells it *how* we're planning to do it; for most "message" types (meaning: something that can itself have sub-values), you almost certainly want `SerializerFeatures.WireTypeString | SerializerFeatures.CategoryMessage`, i.e. "this is a 'message', to be serialized using 'length prefix' semantics by default" (although each call-site can override the wire-type preference if needed).

Some *examples* can be found in the custom serializer used in protobuf-net.Reflection (which needs to work in cases where ref-emit is not allowed, hence the custom serializer); [for example](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/93b8be6118b0fad850c309f5145adbbddb72f487/src/protobuf-net.Reflection/Internal/CustomProtogenSerializer.Services.cs#L2334-L2399) - however, note that most of this code was actually obtained by running the regular protobuf-net ref-emit mechanism to generate a dll, then reverse-engineering the IL from that dll back to C#! I say this as a "if the code looks weird: that's why". I've deliberately linked to a slightly humanized portion of the file, i.e. it uses `switch` instead of `if`. But even then it retains some weirdness - for example the `string local1 = name;` actually comes from a "push, dup, conditional-jump, consume|pop" setup.

Comment: Perfect, that sample helps a bunch. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, just one additional question: Would you say it is a fair assumption that using a custom serializer will help save resources (allocations)?

Comment: @Wolfgang compared to what? surrogates: yes; something else? I'd need more context; however, surrogate allocations are usually transients that are collected in gen-zero, which makes them... not exactly free, but at least: cheapish

Comment: Yes, compared to surrogates. Just looking to be as efficient as possible to avoid problems later on. My plan is to first write the type name to the wire ```state.WriteString(2, newVal.GetType().FullName);``` and then state.WriteBytes() to write the serialized object.

In the reader I would like to do the reverse.... But since there is no "ReadBytes(int fieldNumber) but only state.AppendBytes(byteArray) - do I have to manually prepend the size of the byte array?

Comment: @Wolfgang (re now-deleted comment) that's passing in an empty buffer; I don't have enough context here, but: the thing you're reading/writing - it that *also* protobuf? because once you know the type, you can just serialize the rest directy *using the serializer*, just like any other sub-object; as long as you know the type, you should be fine.

Comment: I have a class that contains a ```public object Prop {get;set;}``` and I would like to write a custom serializer for this class. Within the custom serializer I would like to first write the type name and as second field the (proto) serialized object "Prop" - in the read method I would then like to read out the type name and use it to retrieve the runtime type - then I would like to (proto) deserialize the second field.

Comment: @Wolfgang right; so... just do that? Once you have resolved the type, just use similar code to *any of the other sub-object examples* (in the previously linked custom serializer code) - look for `state.WriteMessage` and `state.ReadMessage`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257209/discussion-between-wolfgang-and-marc-gravell).

Comment: I have created a new question, maybe my issue is clearer this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78185352/how-would-i-write-a-custom-protobuf-net-serializer-for-this-particular-class