# How would I write a custom protobuf-net serializer for this particular class

Tags: protobuf-net

I am trying to write a custom protobuf-net serializer to put a property of type `object` to the wire.

```
[ProtoContract(Serializer=typeof(ChangeRecordSerializer))]
public class ChangeRecord
{
   public object NewValue {get;set;}
}
```

This is where I'm at:

```
public class ChangeRecordSerializer : ISerializer<ChangeRecord>
{
   public void Write(ref ProtoWriter.State state, ChangeRecord value)
   {
      state.WriteString(1, value.NewValue.GetType().FullName;
      // how to serialize value.NewValue???
   }

   public void Read(ref ProtoReader.State state, ChangeRecord value)
   {
      int num = 0;
      string typeName = null;
      while ((num = state.ReadFieldHeader()) > 0)
      {
         switch (num)
         {
            case 1:
               typeName = state.ReadString();
               break;

            case 2:
               var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
               // how to read value.NewValue???
               break;
         }
      }
   }

   public SerializerFeatures Features => SerializerFeatures.CategoryMessage | SerializerFeatures.WireTypeString;
}
```

How do I implement the two commented out lines?

Comment: what are the known/expected/possible values of `NewValue` ? doing this for some finite/known range of types is possible; doing this for any `object`: not so much

Comment: can I change `ChangeRecord` at all, or does everything need to be in the serializer?

Comment: I do not understand why this is not possible. I can easily do the same thing with a surrogate - I serialize / deserialize the type name and then use a second [ProtoMember] of type ```byte[]``` which I then fill with Serializer.NonGeneric.Serialize. I can later on deserialize it with Serializer.NonGeneric.Deserialize (using the type name I also put on the surrogate)

I just want to do an equivalent without instanciating a surrogate for every single object I want to serialize.

Comment: Yes, I can change the ChangeRecord if it is necessary.

Comment: it is absolutely *possible*; I never said anything about it not being possible

Comment: Could you please show me an equivalent to putting type name and ```byte[]``` on the wire using a custom serializer?

Comment: if you write it using the `byte[]` approach: you've added *more* overhead than if you'd just used a surrogate; we don't want a `byte[]` allocation - what we want is to write a sub-object directly (which at the byte level is the exact same output), which means calling back into the serializer for your expected `Order`, `Customer`, `Address`, etc types, and *that* is where it gets awkward if we're in a custom serializer

Comment: Ok I will stick to surrogates then. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using a custom serializer is that (at least currently) once you're at that level: you need to *stay* at that level - meaning: you can't just get the serializer to handle all the expected types: it is expecting you to be explicit *from there downwards*, which gets very awkward. If this was me, I would just use a surrogate, having the surrogate work *similarly* to a discriminated union. This doesn't need to be expensive; consider:

```cs
using ProtoBuf;

Show(32);
Show("abc");
Show(new Foo { Bar = "banana" });

static void Show(object value)
{
    var obj = new ChangeRecord { NewValue = value };
    var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(obj);
    Console.WriteLine($"{obj.NewValue} => {clone.NewValue}");
}


[ProtoContract(Surrogate = typeof(ChangeRecordSurrogate))]
public class ChangeRecord
{
    public object? NewValue { get; set; }
}


[ProtoContract]
public class Foo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string? Bar { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => $"Foo: {Bar}";
}


[ProtoContract]
struct ChangeRecordSurrogate
{
    public static implicit operator ChangeRecordSurrogate(ChangeRecord value)
        => new ChangeRecordSurrogate { Value = value?.NewValue };
    public static implicit operator ChangeRecord(ChangeRecordSurrogate value)
        => new ChangeRecord { NewValue = value.Value! };

    public object? Value { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int? ValueInt32
    {
        get => Value is int x ? x : default;
        set => Value = value;
    }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string? ValueString
    {
        get => Value as string;
        set => Value = value;
    }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public Foo? ValueFoo
    {
        get => Value as Foo;
        set => Value = value;
    }
}
```